# Assigning (download) links to my queried results

Tags: php, sql, database, hyperlink, download

So I've been bashing my head on this problem for some time and i just cant find an example to get it working for my own piece of code. Now i am hoping that some of you got a solution for me, or at least point me in the right direction. So the problem is the following:

A person can upload certain files and information to a database. The uploading of the files, so the file name, is in the same database row as its name, location etc. So for example: a person has several required fields such as name, location and upload file which together form one row in the database. This works all fine and the files are being uploaded to a folder named: uploads/participant-database (entire name is: mytestsite.nl:2222/CMD_FILE_MANAGER/domains/mytestsite.nl/public_html/Recap/wp-content/uploads/participants-database).

However, the problem is, that the person also can search for the database data (and retrieve it) by using a checkbox search system. Based on the persons given checkbox options, certain data (that matches the selection) is being showed. The question however is: how can i assign the downlaod links to the right database values? Ill make it a bit clearer with some images below:

[Picture with the displaying / retrieving of the database information](http://s30.postimg.org/t2ulogtyp/Example_picture_1.png)

The code which retrieves the database information is as follows (i just took 1 filter to give the query idea because else it would be a to big piece of code):

```
if(!empty($_POST['columns_location']) && !empty($_POST['columns_theme'])) { // empty() checks if the value is set before checking if it's empty.

    // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
        $clean_criteria_location = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['columns_location']);

        // Convert the array into a string.
        $criteria_location = implode("|",$clean_criteria_location);             

// Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
        $clean_criteria_theme = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['columns_theme']);

        // Convert the array into a string.
        $criteria_theme = implode("|",$clean_criteria_theme);               

    $tmp = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT
            name_of_living_lab, location_of_living_lab, type_of_living_lab, theme_of_living_lab, stage_of_living_lab, living_lab_document           
        FROM           
            wp_participants_database            
        WHERE 
            location_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria_location') AND theme_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria_theme') 
        ORDER BY 
            name_of_living_lab ASC
    "); 
}
```

The code that displays the results is as follows:

```
echo "<table>
    <tr>";     
        echo "<th>Name of Living Lab</th>";
        echo "<th>Location of Living Lab</th>"; 
        echo "<th>Type of Living Lab</th>"; 
        echo "<th>Theme of Living Lab</th>";
        echo "<th>Stage of Living Lab</th>";    
        echo "<th>Living Lab document</th>";    
echo "</tr>";


if(count($tmp)>0){
    for($i=0;$i<count($tmp);$i++){
        echo "<tr>";  
            foreach($tmp[$i] as $key=>$value){              

            echo "<td>";

            $b=unserialize($value);

                if(is_array($b)){ 

                array_filter($b); 
                $counttwo = 0;
                    foreach($b as $y){
                    if ($counttwo++ > 1) echo ", ";
                    echo $y;
                    } 
                }

                else{
                    echo $value;
                }
            echo "</td>";                                                   
            }    
        echo "</tr>";

    }
}   
echo '</table>';
```

Now the question is, how do i assign the right links to the queried results? So in the picture example you can see a document table (which is a result of the query) and this text in it should be clickable and downloadable with THAT stored document. So i guess the $tmp result value should be checked for only the database column: documents and then the link should be created which connects the database value to the right document. Though, i have absolutely no idea how to do this (even after quite some research).

I hope you guys can help me or can give me some pointers! Thank you in advance!

*****UPDATE*****
The new display code (which doesn't work since it outputs the text 2 times) with the added suggestions of @dHaRa uMaraniYa :

```
if(count($tmp)>0){
    for($i=0;$i<count($tmp);$i++){
        echo "<tr>";  
            foreach($tmp[$i] as $key=>$value){              

            echo "<td>";

            if($key =='DOC'){ 
                    echo '<a href="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
                }

            $b=unserialize($value);

            if(is_array($b)){ 

                array_filter($b); 
                $counttwo = 0;
                    foreach($b as $y){
                    if ($counttwo++ > 1) echo ", ";
                    echo $y;
                    } 
                }


                else{
                    echo $value;
                }
            echo "</td>";                                                   
            }    
        echo "</tr>";

    }
}   
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: My guess is: if you var_dump($tmp[$i]), you will see keys and values, you could add an if with $key = 'living_lab_document' and create the a-tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select living_lab_document as **DOC**

```
 $tmp = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT
                name_of_living_lab, location_of_living_lab, type_of_living_lab, theme_of_living_lab, stage_of_living_lab, living_lab_document as DOC
            FROM           
                wp_participants_database            
            WHERE 
                location_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria_location') AND theme_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria_theme') 
            ORDER BY 
                name_of_living_lab ASC
        ");
```

and check that if

```
if($key =='DOC'){ 
  echo '<a href="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
else
{
echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you a lot! i will test it right a way! Its actually seems not that hard, yet it is so hard to think of:)

Comment: I have tested the code though, two problems remain. The first (and easiest) is that the link is created but the  link text is being output 2 times, one time as a clickable link and the second time just as plain text, like so: aipa_care_living_lab_-_information.pdfaipa_care_living_lab_-_information.pdf whereby the first is clickable. The second problem is that the link doesn't return me to an unknown page rather then just starting the download on the same page (with a redirection to the right folder which contains the file). I added the new result display code in my 1 post.

Comment: alright, nevermind the second problem as i posted it without thinking. I fixed the href with the proper link.

Comment: Nevermind the first problem as well, got it all fixed now, once more thank you for your answer!